# Logout Button causes crash in my android app

Tags: android, json

Hi  well im trying to build an android app with account features using JSON with MYSQL. I was able to login but whenever I log out it causes a crash

code snippet for onclick event

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getActivity());
```

Here is my logout function from my userfunctions class

```
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);

        return true;
```

Logcat Report

```
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): Process: com.learn2crack.tab, PID: 1455
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.learn2crack.library.UserFunctions.logoutUser(UserFunctions.java:115)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.learn2crack.tab.Profile$2.onClick(Profile.java:92)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-22 16:47:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have done some more searching for answers and came up with adding this code

```
public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }
```

But the PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE are having the error line it says it cannot be resolved into a variable but the example I read didn't require any declaration

Comment: yep everything was declared.

Comment: How are you declaring them?

Comment: I have declared it in the same way they are declared in a sessionmanager class Editor editor;
  Context _context;

Comment: UserFunctions is created in the previous line of the logoutUser call. If you didn't initialize them in the constructor of UserFunctions _context and editor will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace is telling you that the problem is in the line 115 of UserFunctions.

Is it this? (shouldn't you be using the parameter `context`?)

```
_context.startActivity(i);
```

Or this?

```
editor.clear();
```

Edit:
UserFunctions is created in the previous line of the logoutUser call. If you didn't initialize them in the constructor of UserFunctions `_context` and `editor` will be null.

Try this:

```
public static final String PREF_NAME = "whatever";

public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        context.startActivity(i);

        return true;
}
```

Comment: huh line 115 is indeed editor.clear(); still can't understand what's wrong with it though?

Comment: I updated my answer, now logoutUser use just the context parameter

Answer (score 0):

I was able  to get it to work by  initialazing private_mode with
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
pomber's answer of initializing with public static final String PREF_NAME = "whatever"; 
 gave me the idea

Comment: What's the point to post an answer? edit the original question with the solution.

Comment: You shouldnt use PRIVATE_MODE = 0, use [Context.MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE).